# How to use UPDATE JOIN correctly?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, sql-update

I tried to update a table row as below:

```
update EMPLOYEE set Salary=Salary * 1.15 where Dno=1;
```

which works fine, but I wanted to learn how to use UPDATE JOIN. so I use the Department Name instead of DNo.

I wrote below code:

```
update EMPLOYEE  set Salary=e.Salary * 1.15 from EMPLOYEE e join DEPARTMENT d on e.DNo=d.DNumber  where d.DName='Headquarters';
```

But the result for above code is that the SQL Command updates all the rows in EMPLOYEE table.
Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, change this to a filter in the `where` clause:

```
update EMPLOYEE e
    set Salary = Salary * 1.15 
    where exists (select 1
                  from DEPARTMENT d 
                  where d.DNumber = e.DNo and
                        d.DName = 'Headquarters'
                 );
```

The above is standard SQL and should work in any database.  If you want a `FROM` clause, then use:

```
update EMPLOYEE e
    set Salary = e.Salary * 1.15 
    from DEPARTMENT d 
    where d.DNumber = e.DNo and
          d.DName = 'Headquarters';
```

There are (at least) two different ways of implementing `FROM` in an update, the "SQL Server method" and the "Postgres" method.  In the SQL Server method, the table being updated should be in the `FROM` clause.  In the "Postgres method", the table *cannot* be in the `FROM` clause.  BigQuery adheres to the "Postgres method".

The above actually works in both methods, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use table alias name in update

```
update Emp
Set Salary = Emp.Salary * 1.15 
From EMPLOYEE As Emp
join DEPARTMENT As dep On Emp.DNo = dep.DNumber  
Where dep.DName = 'Headquarters';
```

Comment: Thank you for response, It does not work. ( update Emp has issues ) even if I add the full table name (update Employee) , it still update all the rows